# How do I reverse engineer this truth table?

Tags: circuit, truthtable

How Do I know which functions were performed to get this truth table?
Any help Appreciated

The truth table:
[image: The truth table]

Comment: Do you want the algebraic expression?

Comment: @TobiasWilfert yeah

Comment: like which functions were performed on three lines to get 4th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algebraic expression is:
Sum of products: `~y*~z+x*z`
Product of sums: `(x+~z)*(~y+z)`

Comment: what do you mean by not(y)not(z)

Comment: Does it mean that ~y AND ~z?

Comment: @user9104051 Yes

Comment: I have one more question, how will I get the same thing using only nand gates

Comment: @user9104051 Glad, I could help feel free to accept my answer for reputation sake.

Comment: @user9104051 are you using any software to build your circuit?

Comment: @user9104051 a NAND is ~(A*B) so if you pass twice the same value to a NAND you get the invert of the value ~(A*A)->~(A). The circuit will use 2 layers of AND gates which makes adding NAND gates supper easy as 2 NAND gates make a double negation and what you are left with is a working circuit.

Comment: @user9104051 the expression will be the following: ~(~(~(y y) ~(z z)) ~(x z))

Comment: I am still confused with this

Comment: Two nand gates will make and and gate  ~(~(y)) = y?

Comment: @user9104051 That is why questions on SO are not really asked in the comment section as one can not structure his answer to the question making it confusing.

Comment: yeah got it thanks for helping me out, appreciate it

Comment: @user9104051 A*A => A; ~(A*A) => ~A; ~(~(A*A)) => A